# Passing Dynamic Name Selector Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I can not create a dynamic input name selector? What I am trying to do is passing the name of the selector dynamically based on Bootstrap Tab functionality.

```js
var checkname;

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
  checkname = target.substring(1);
});


$("input:checkbox[name=" + checkname + "]").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert('Checked');
  } else {
    alert('Un Checked');
  }
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class=""><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
        <input type="checkbox" name="home" value="unit-in-group">Home
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        <input type="checkbox" name="profile" value="unit-in-group">Profile
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By the time when the variable is used it is `undefined`, move the code of binding event at the end of `show.bs.modal`

Comment: $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {.....shown.bs.tab is custom event?

Comment: @Tushar, Thanks for comment but not sure what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend @tushar's comment:

> By the time when the variable is used it is `undefined`, move the code of binding event at the end of `show.bs.modal`

The problem is that the event `show.bs.tab` is called asynchrone and therefore the variable will not be set when you try to access it in `$("input:checkbox[name="+checkname+"]")`. What you can do it make sure you will first bind the `change` event when the `show.bs.modal` event is triggered.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  // Activated tab
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
  // When we have the target we can bind the change event - not before!
  bindChange(target.slice(1));
});

function bindChange(checkname) {

  $("input:checkbox[name="+checkname+"]").on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      alert('Checked');
    }
    else {
      alert('Un Checked');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks dev-null this is working but I have some questions? First of all, @Tushar just commented to ` move the code of binding event at the end of show.bs.modal` but you are making a function `bindChange()` are theses same? and can you please explain alittle bit  what is exactly happening in you code

Comment: @Suffii Yes it is the same. I just made the function to structure the code into different parts. Lets say you want to bind the event on another time, then you can simply call `bindChange('qwerty')`. I also edited the answer to explain the execution flow.